# Uno de mis JLabels no se actualiza correctamente

Tags: java, java-swing

tengo un pequeno ahorcado creado con swing y sockets. Pero me he topado con un problema
que no consigo solucionar.

Uno de los JLabels que hay en el frame no se actualiza usando setText, mientras que el resto de los JLabels se actualizan perfectamente.

Dejo a mi mi codigo, muchas gracias!

He probado con repaint() y con validate(), revalidate, paintImmediately.. pero nada parece funcionar.

```
    private void ObtenerRespuesta() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        
        // REINICIAR DIBUJO AHORCADO 
        dibujo.setText("");
        
        // CREAR STREAM PARA RECIBIR OBJETOS A PARTIR DE IS
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
    
        // LEER PAQUETE DEL SERVIDOR
        Paquete paquete = (Paquete) ois.readObject();
        
        System.out.println("He recibido el paquete" + paquete.getPalabra() + ", " + paquete.getError());
        
        // COMPROBAR SI ES DE TIPO ERROR
        if(!paquete.getError().equals(""))
        {
            //info.setText(paquete.getError());
        }
        
        // MOSTRAR CONTENIDOS DEL PAQUETE EN PANTALLA
        else
        {
            incognitas.setText(paquete.getPalabra());
            dibujo.setText(paquete.getHorca());
        }
        if(paquete.isFinPartida())
        {
////////// ESTE ES EL SETTEXT QUE NO FUNCIONA, EL SYSTEM OUT SE HACE CORRECTAMENTE. ///
            System.out.println("FIN PARTIDA");
            info.setText("Fin de la partida");
        }
    }
```

Gracias por echarle un ojo!

Comment: Has intentado con updateUI()?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: ya intentaste usando swingUtilities para delegar tareas al hilo gráfico?